# Invoke-RestMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ''

Tags: powershell

I'm not able to understand why my code is failing.

```
$Param = @{
    Uri = ("https://api.crowdstrike.com/policy/combined/reveal-uninstall-token/v1")
    Method = 'post'
    Headers = @{
        'Content-type' = 'application/json'
        authorization = "$($Token.token_type) $($Token.access_token)"
    }
}

$data = @{
    audit_message="test api"
    device_id='111111111111111111111111111'
}

$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json

$uninstall = Invoke-RestMethod @Param -Body @json
```

Error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ''.
At line:48 char:14
+ $uninstall = Invoke-RestMethod @Param -Body @json
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I'm passing the data as JSON (as required per the below screen shot):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Any hints please ?

Thank you !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeRaj.png

Comment: Change `@json` to `$json`

Comment: Or add `json = $data | ConvertTo-Json` to your `$param = @{...}` block. The reason you get the error is the `@` symbol is used to tell a cmdlet to take each of the hash table's keys as a named parameter. `$json` is not a hash table, so the command receives nothing.